# Demonopolise or de monopolise?

Tags: grammar, spelling

I'm preparing for academic IELTS by writing some essays and then correcting those using a grammar correction app.

In the following sentence,

> If governments will find ways to effectively minimise corruption and
> to demonopolise the market, ...

The app suggests using "de monopolise" instead of "demonopolise". Is it a critical mistake? Is there any difference in terms of meaning or tone?

Comment: "de monopolise" is certainly wrong.  I'm not sure if it should be hyphenated or one word, but two words is definitely wrong.

Comment: Grammar correction apps are almost always terrible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Demonopoloize" is the standard spelling.  If you feel this is hard to read, because it seems to be "demon-opolize" you are free to use a hyphen to clarify the splitting:  "de-monopolize".

If you use a style guide, you can check to see which form it prefers, otherwise use what you prefer and be consistent.

A similar example is "re-enter" or "reenter" both of which are used. You can pick the form that you prefer.

Comment: "Reënter" would also be considered valid according to some archaic guides. You virtually never see it today though.